# "no public key available" while upgrading using update-manager

Tags: apt, gnupg

I decided to upgrade

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Then it's opening the update-manger GUI. After clicking the upgrade button It's return the below error list:

```
W:There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32,
W:There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32,
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This warning means that you don't have the corresponding public keys for these repositories.

```
W:There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32,
W:There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32,
```

Verify that these keys are indeed the ones you need. In this case:

```
➜  ~ gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --search-key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpg: searching for "3B4FE6ACC0B21F32" from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
(1) Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
      4096 bit RSA key C0B21F32, created: 2012-05-11
Keys 1-1 of 1 for "3B4FE6ACC0B21F32".  Enter number(s), N)ext, or Q)uit >
```

The ID correspond to Ubuntu Archive. It is strange that you are missing these keys. This is normally fixed with:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

After this, run `sudo apt-get update` and make sure no other warnings/errors appear.

Comment: Master answer. I hope this does not indicate funny business or vulnerability on the server.

Comment: In my case, it was simply a 3rd party repository whose public key had expired. The above steps installed the new public key, and my `apt-get update` subsequently was squeaky clean.